# Facebook SDK PHP 2.8 Invalid parameter when link parameter included

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

When i post a message to a page it works fine however, if I add a link parameter to the $data array it returns an error.

Anyone experience this?

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
   'app_id' => $config['app_id'],
   'app_secret' => $config['app_secret'],
   'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
]);

$access_token = "12345";

$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($access_token);

$data = [
   "message" => "hello",
   "link" => "www.bbc.co.uk"
];

$page_id = 123;

try {
   $response = $fb->post('/' . $page_id . '/feed', $data);

} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
   echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
   exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
   echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
   exit;
}

print_r($response);
```

Comment: You need to use an absolute URL, including a protocol.

Comment: @CBroe, I don't think this is right. I had to turn off "Stream post URL security" in my apps security settings. This allowed me to links not on my domain.

Comment: Yes, that has to be deactivated of course. But you should still use a proper, absolute URL that includes the protocol.